# how to match the contents of two arrays and get corresponding index ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

**Original Question**: The original question was how to iterate to the next element in nested loop ruby. The answer taught an idiomatic approach to solve my problem and it needed a different question, so that when a user lands up here on googling, finds the correct thing

I have this requirement where there are two arrays, and each of them have unique values, in sorted order.

```
array1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7] #can not have repeated values[2,2,3]
array2 = [2,5,7]
```

I want to match elements of both arrays and print `match found` whenever a match is found, along with the index of both the arrays. This is the code which works fine.

```
array1.each do |arr1|
  array2.each do |arr2|
    if (arr1==arr2)
      puts ("Match found element #{arr1} #{array1.index(arr1)} #{array2.index(arr2)}")
      #some code here to move to the next element in array 1 and array 2 and continue looping from there
    end
  end
end
```

But this does not use the data structure's quality of being unique and sorted in any way. For instance, when in the above example, element `2` in `array1` matches element `2` in `array2`, the element `2` in `array2` should not continue trying to match other elements of `array1` and also `array1` should  be moved to the next. I know there is something called `next`. But I think that just returns the next element and does not move the iterator to the next element? Also I have to move to the next of both the arrays. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find matching elements between two arrays just use `&` like so:

```
array1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7] #does not have repeated values[2,2,3] and the values are sorted
array2 = [2,5,7]

matches = array1 & array2
 => [2, 5, 7]
```

To print the matches and indexes found in each array, just loop through the matches array like so:

```
matches.each do |number|
  puts "Match found element #{number}"
  puts "array1 index=#{array1.rindex(number)}"
  puts "array2 index=#{array2.rindex(number)}"
end

Match found element 2
array1 index=0
array2 index=0
Match found element 5
array1 index=3
array2 index=1
Match found element 7
array1 index=5
array2 index=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I didn't know I could do this way also, but my requirement is not just thematch but actually i wanted to get the index of both the arrays where the elements matched. for example this would return `array1 index=0 array2 index=0` then `array1 index=3 array2 index=1` and `array1 index=5 array index=2`. so how do i get next. i will edit the question now.

Comment: In my solution, you don't have to move to the next element. You first find the numbers that occur in both arrays. Then you find the index by getting the `rindex` of the letter. `rindex` tells you the index where an element appears in an array.

Comment: Yeah, got it thanks.. btw how does matches=array1&array2 works?

Comment: The `&` operator will take two arrays as arguments and return the numbers that both arrays contain. So when you call `array1 & array2`, it returns an array of the numbers that occurs in both arrays. Example: `[1,2,3] & [1,3,5]` will return `[1,3]`

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'm more in love with ruby now. The idiomatic code rocks! thanks a ton

Comment: @Inquisitive, I feel the same way about ruby. It really is a beautiful language. =]

Comment: Is there a difference between rindex and index? that is what difference does it make if I search from the last using rindex and search from the beginning using index?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. Actually, I just realized that both can be used in this scenario, since there are unique numbers in the original arrays (`array1` and `array2`). `index` will search from the beginning of the array and find the first occurrence. `rindex`, or reverse index, will search from the end of the array and find the first occurrence.

Comment: Does that affect optimizing the code. Not really. right? I mean both are same. using rindex or index

Comment: In this scenario, not really, no.

Comment: One  more thing, basically my intention was to avoid extra matches. does using `array1 & array2` do that? How does it return the array of numbers that exist in both arrays? does it match each value of array1 with array2? This question later succumbs to, using idiomatic code or self optimized code. what is better?

Comment: The `&` will only return unique matches so you don't get extra matches. Example: `[1,1,2] & [1,2,2]` will return `[1,2]`. See the `intersection` method for arrays here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html to see how the code works. It essentially sees what elements exist in one array and keeps track of the unique elements. Then it goes through the other array and if an element is discovered then it is kept. Otherwise, it is deleted. You end up with the intersection of the two arrays.

Comment: What if this is a string array and I want to merge the strings, but their comparison should be case insensitive. Should I store the strings in downcase, or can I use casecmp in some way?

Answer (score 3):

For your codes, you just need to use `break` to exit the array2 loop, move to the next element in array1.

```
array2.each_with_index do |arr1, i1|
   array1.each_with_index do |arr2, i2|
     if (arr1==arr2)
       puts ("Match found element array1: #{arr1} #{i1} and array2: #{arr2} #{i2}")
       #if match element is found, exit from the current loop
       break
     end
   end
    end
Match found element array1: 2 0 and array2: 2 0
Match found element array1: 5 1 and array2: 5 3
Match found element array1: 7 2 and array2: 7 5
```

or

```
(array1 & array2).map{ |e| puts "Match found element #{e}" }
Match found element 2
Match found element 5
Match found element 7
```

Comment: Nice idiomatic approach but I  wanted to get the index of both the arrays where the elements matched. for example this would return `array1 index=0 array2 index=0 then array1 index=3 array2 index=1 and array1 index=5 array index=2`. so how do i get next. i will edit the question now.

Comment: Yeah, this also works but it just moves to the next on finding a match in array1 only. For the next element of array1, it will again begin from 0th element of array2. I wanted to optimize the code , it optimizes but not for both the loops. btw how does the idiomatic code of using array1 & array2 works? does it do some optimizations, internally?

Comment: If you change two arrays positions, you will get better performance.

Comment: you mean changing array1 with array2? but this is just a sample code. i never know, whether array1 contains more elements or array2. May be I need to use size/length method for that and proceed. Also see my last comment in the accepted answer. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
array1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
array2 = [2,5,7]

h = array1.each_with_index.to_h
  #=> {2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>4, 7=>5} 

array2.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(v,i),g| g[v] = [h[v],i] if h.key?(v) }
  #=> {2=>[0, 0], 5=>[3, 1], 7=>[5, 2]}
```

The second expression can be broken down as follows:

```
e0 = array2.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 5, 7]:each_with_index>
```

We can see the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
e0.to_a
  #=> [[2, 0], [5, 1], [7, 2]] 

e1 = e0.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [2, 5,7]:each_with_index>:with_object({})> 
e1.to_a
  #=> [[[2, 0], {}], [[5, 1], {}], [[7, 2], {}]]
```

The elements of the enumerator `e` are passed to the block and assigned to the block variables by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each). The first (obtained using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)) is:

```
(v,i),g = e1.next
  #=> [[2, 0], {}] 
v #=> 2 
i #=> 0 
g #=> {}
```

We can now execute the block:

```
g[v] = [h[v],i] if h.key?(v)
  #=> g[2] = [h[2],0] if h.key(v)
  #   g[2] = [0,0] if true
```

The next element of `e1` is now passed to the block:

```
(v,i),g = e1.next
  #=> [[5, 1], {}] 
v #=> 5 
i #=> 1 
g #=> {2=>[0, 0]} 
g[v] = [h[v],i] if h.key?(v)
  # g[5] = [h[5], 1] if h.key?(5)
  # g[5] = [3, 1] if true

g #=> {2=>[0, 0], 5=>[3, 1]}
```

The calculation for the last element of `e1` is similar.

Comment: Nice, can you explain the code `array2.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(v,i),g| g[v] = [h[v],i] if h.key?(v) }`? I didn't understand the block here

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: hey, that explains everything. Thanks a lot.